# Swift NSURLConnection doesn't have a member named start

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection

```
 var connection = NSURLConnection(request: theRequest, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
 connection.start()
```

ERROR:
NSURLConnection doesn't have a member named start

Any idea ? why start not work here :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other posters have noted, since you're passing `true` as `startImmediately`, you don't actually need to call `start`, but that doesn't explain why it isn't found.

```
var connection = NSURLConnection(request: theRequest, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
```

returns an optional (the request may not be processable by `NSURLConnection`) so you have to unwrap it, any of:

```
connection!.start()

connection?.start()

if let connection = connection {
    connection.start()
}
else {
    // handle error case
}
```

will work for you, in increasing order of preference/safety.

Comment: just tried this, and if you put connection?.start() you won't have any error.

Answer (score -1):

This wont work.

Please check documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLConnection/start

In particular

> Calling this method is necessary only if you create a connection with
>   the initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately: method and provide NO
>   for the startImmediately parameter. If you don’t schedule the
>   connection in a run loop or an operation queue before calling this
>   method, the connection is scheduled in the current run loop in the
>   default mode.

In order to make start work, you have to change `startImmediately: true` to `startImmediately: false`